# How to impose weight symmetries in Lasagne

Tags: neural-network, theano, lasagne

I'm working with Lasagne on a neural network.

I want that on the first layer, the same weight is applied to many neurons of the input layer (and obviously I want that weights update considering the contribute of all these neurons)

This because my input has many symmetries: I have 24*n different inputs but I want only 4*n different weights (n is a parameter that I still need to decide)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `theano.shared` variables, e.g.:

```
l_in = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(10)
weights = theano.shared(np.zeros(10, 100))
layer_1 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_in, num_units=100, W=weights)
layer_2 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_in, num_units=100, W=weights)
layer_3 = lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(l_in, num_units=100, b=layer_2.b)
```

this way `layer_1` will have the same weights as `layer_2` and `layer_2` will have the same biases as `layer_3`.

http://lasagne.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/layers.html#parameter-sharing